# How can I move the focus in Outlook to the list of emails with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

It seems like it should be simple but I haven't found an answer yet.  I am trying to use VBA to move the focus to the Outlook pane that lists email in the currently opened folder.  The issue is setting the focus to a pane within the Outlook window, (as opposed to the entire window).

[image]

I won't know where the focus will be so I don't want to use SendKeys to send a keystroke like TAB or ALT+TAB to navigate between panes.

I found that switching to a different folder and then back to the same one seems to do the trick, but that seems like a messy workaround.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: The way to *take* focus away from a UI element, is to *give* the focus to some other element. Get a hold of the current mailitem, and set focus there?

Comment: What I mean is I won't know where the focus will be –before– my code attempts to change the focus to the area I called out in the screenshot above.  If I know focus is on the preview pane I can send an ALT+TAB keystroke to shift focus to the email list.  If I know focus is on the folder/navigation pane I can sent a TAB keystroke to get me there.  Is there any way to identify the pane that has focus?   What about a method to shift the focus without keystrokes?

Comment: Maybe `Screen.ActiveControl`?